# How to put an if else statement in a loop

Tags: c#

This is my code. So far this works but I need it to be in a loop, so I don't keep repeating the `if else` statement.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int i, j, k, l, m, n;
            int result;
            string [] array = { "abcw", "baz", "foo", "bar", "xtfn", "abcdef" };
            i = array[0].Length;
            j = array[1].Length;
            k = array[2].Length; 
            l = array[3].Length;
            m = array[4].Length;
            n = array[5].Length;
            result = i * j;
            if (result == 16) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine(result);
            }
            else
            {
                result = i * k;
            }
            if (result == 16)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(result);
            }
            else
            {
                result = i * l;
            }
            if (result == 16)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(result);
            }
            else
            {
                result = i * m;
            }
            if (result == 16)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(array[0]+" * "+array[4]+" = "+result);
            }
            else
            {
                result = i * n;
            }
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take a minute to take the [tour], especially [ask].Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take a minute to take the [tour], especially How to [Ask], and [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: Does it go all the way to m*n?

Comment: Yes please it does

Comment: What is your target by this code? If `result !=16` then what is your expected result?

Comment: If it's! = 16 it should just return 0

Comment: @Md. Suman Kabir

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the possible way to short your code.

You can iterate your array and compare first item with rest of the items as you mentioned in your question code-block. No need to access individual array elements.

**Compare 1st element with rest**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int result;
    string[] array = { "abcw", "baz", "foo", "bar", "xtfn", "abcdef" };

    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length - 2; i++)
    {
        result = array[0].Length * array[i + 1].Length;

        if (result == 16)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(array[0] + " * " + array[i+1] + " = " + result);
            break;
        }
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

**Compare all element in between**

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    for (var j = i + 1; j < array.Length; j++)
        if (array[i].Length * array[j].Length == 16)
            Console.WriteLine(array[i] + " * " + array[j] + " = " + array[i].Length * array[j].Length);
```

Comment: This only works because one of the elements in the solution is the first one. If you swap the first 2 elements so array becomes `"baz", "abcw", "foo", "bar", "xtfn", "abcdef"` then it doesn't find it.

Comment: @HansKilian I correct it. Thanks for drawing attention!

Comment: Thank you  very much. but also if the first string * the others doesn't get the answer I want it to move to the second string  * the others and on like that until the answer is found

Comment: @AbolarinAnuoluwapo I updated my answer. Check the **Compare all element in between** part. It will do as you want.

Comment: @Gaurang Dave  thank you very much..  It has worked  but what if I want to filter the array of strings and remove strings that have the same characters in them before doing the operation

Comment: @AbolarinAnuoluwapo You are welcome. Please mark as answer if working. Kindly ask separate question for other functionality to maintain rules of SO. I will surely respond to you. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you create an outer loop that loops over all the entries and then an inner loop that loops over the entries after the one you're looking at in the outer loop, you can do something like this

```
      string[] array = {"abcw", "baz", "foo", "bar", "xtfn", "abcdef"};
      for (var i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
      {
          for (var j = i + 1; j < array.Length; j++)
          {
              if (array[i].Length * array[j].Length == 16)
              {
                  Console.WriteLine($"{array[i]} {array[j]}");
              }
          }
      }
```

You then get the result which is `abcw xtfn`

Comment: Your solution is working. I think there is no need for two loops. Can achieve in single loop.

Comment: See my reply to your solution

Comment: would be better to check this solution for 9 or 24 instead of 16, that way you can really see if the solution is correct. (It seems correct by reading it, though).

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] array = { "abcw", "baz", "foo", "bar", "xtfn", "abcdef" };
        int result = 16;
        for (var i = 0; i < array.Length; i++) {
            int x = array[i].Length;
            if (result % x != 0) {
                continue;
            }
            for (var j = i + 1; j < array.Length; j++) {
                if (x * array[j].Length == result) {
                    Console.WriteLine(array[i] + "*" + array[j] + "= " + result);
                }
            }
        }
```